# ExceptionInInitializerError for db2

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, db2

I have the simplest JDBC program to read data from a DB2 (or other configured) instance. When I attempt to run it from Eclipse OR from the command line, the connect fails, throwing a SQLexception

```
 Class.forName(jdbcDriverClassName).newInstance();
```

The class.forName fails, using  `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`.  I configured Eclipse to point to the same driver that DBVisualizer uses (both as a boot library and for the project).  The program uses the same connect string that DBVisualizer uses.  DBVisualizer isn't having any trouble.

Ouptut w/full stack (note the FQN for the driver is not null):

```
                   V-- !null driver name --V
Attempting to load com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
ERROR:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.class$(DB2Driver.java:58)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.<clinit>(DB2Driver.java:61)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at com.onlineretailer.ecomm.dumporder.DumpOrder.main(DumpOrder.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.i(ib.java:490)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.<clinit>(ib.java:420)
... 7 more
```

I also tried adding the .newInstance() to the end of the class.forName() and it continues to execute the same behavior.

Thanks to everyone for your time and input!

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2:...
> ```

This exception has only 2 possible causes:

1. The JDBC driver is unknown with [`DriverManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html). I.e. the JDBC driver has not registered itself properly by [`DriverManager#registerDriver()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver%28java.sql.Driver%29).
2. The JDBC URL is unknown for any of the JDBC drivers registered with `DriverManager`. I.e. the [`Driver#acceptsURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#acceptsURL%28java.lang.String%29) hasn't returned `true` for any of the registered drivers.

Your JDBC driver class name is perfectly fine. Your JDBC URL is perfectly fine.

A **well designed** JDBC driver registers itself with `DriverManager` in a `static {}` initializer block which get executed upon `Class#forName()`. However, older versions of the IBM DB2 JDBC driver registers itself in the *constructor* instead. For those broken drivers you need to call [`newInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) afterwards as well.

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
```

#### See also:

- [Loading JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992126/loading-jdbc-driver)
- [Is the DriverManager concept in JDBC based on the provider design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066598/is-the-drivermanager-concept-in-jdbc-based-on-the-provider-design-pattern)

---

**Update** as per your question update, the `newInstance()` *did* the trick. It however leads to a *new* problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.i(ib.java:490)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.<clinit>(ib.java:420)
```

It turns out to be another bug in the DB2 JDBC Driver itself. Upgrade it.

Comment: @BalusC: There is a third cause: registered driver was loaded by a wrong classloader.

Comment: @axtavt: nice one :) That would have been a terrible classloader hierarchy. I only don't think that OP runs a heavy Java EE application with multiple classloaders.

Comment: @axtavt: thanks. I think perhaps I'm running into the third cause. The driver JARs are now in the system classpath, in every classpath possible, and the error still occurs.  The reason I posted is because i've done more than my fair share of jdbc programming in the past, and why it would work for DBVis and not for me is what left me scratching my head.

Comment: @Alexx: so, calling `newInstance()` afterwards doesn't solve it? What DB2 JDBC driver version exactly are you using?

Comment: @BalusC: sadly, it did not. (I'd seen that also in another post - perhaps it was you (-:)  I have also tried including the license JAR in the CP, in case this was a spurious error of sorts. (db2jcc_license_cu.jar) I am uncertain of the difference between the two JARs distributed by IBM and what DBVis is utilizing.

Comment: As a *test*, try replacing the `Class#forName()` line by `DriverManager.registerDriver(new DB2Driver());`.

Comment: Wait, I see in your updated question code that you're totally suppressing the `Throwable e`. Don't do that, rethrow it or do at least `e.printStackTrace()`. This way the *real* problem becomes clear -if any.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder (didn't encounter this trouble with the other db so I'd genericized my error handling). I'll update with the full stack. Much more informative <smacks forehead>

Comment: OK. This appears to be a Java security issue?   https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IY78176

Comment: @BalusC: I truly do appreciate all of your assistance.  When I unmasked the exception the originally reported one still continues to be thrown, only after the ExceptionInInitializerError. The same error is thrown and same stack is reported for `Class.forName(jdbcDriverClassName).newInstance()`,`Class.forName(jdbcDriverClassName)`, or `DriverManager.registerDriver(new DB2Driver())`.

Comment: The first one is fine, the second one should be the right way but apparently doesn't work for the particular JDBC driver (as your initial problem stated), the third was just for test to naildown the problem better. Right now, I really can't be of more help than recommending to upgrade the JDBC driver to a newer version. Any `RuntimeException` is basically a bug (a developer's mistake) in the code and since the JDBC driver code is completely out of your control...

Answer (score 1):

You need to load driver too in your jvm , using `Class.forName()`
You need to load following driver

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Here is how it fully look like

```
String databaseURL = "jdbc:derby:net://localhost:1527/sample";
// Load DB2 Driver for JDBC class
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
// Set user and password properties
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("user", "APP");
properties.put("password", "APP");
properties.put("retreiveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage", "true");
// Get a connection
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, properties);
```

---

**Reference**

- [DB2 Driver for JDBC examples](http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/adminguide/radminapps810699.html)

Comment: Thanks, I have that line prior to the call to getConnection:                   private static final String jdbcDriverClassName = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
...Class.forName(jdbcDriverClassName);

Comment: Print the whole stack trace.  That error message is less information than what's available.

Comment: So it should be working now , or is there any trouble still ?>

Comment: You need to add [`jdbc db2 driver jar`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) in your class path too

Comment: Ack. stackoverflow just barfed on my edits. I will have to update later.

Comment: I have edited your post , its better now. As I said in my previous comment you need to add driver jar too :)

Answer (score 0):

"No suitable driver" usually means that the connection URL isn't correct for the JAR you're using.